# Isn't this pretty much the same thing?

Tags: us20110114526

In reference to the patent: [US20110114526](https://www.google.com/patents/US20110114526)

Compartmentalized food and beverage cooler device 
US 20040262319 A1

Isnt this pretty much the same thing, just different dimensions and design?...no invention here...

Comment: Multi-compartment container and lid assembly 
US 20040129707 A1

Comment: Weir also shows a very similar design with sealed individual compartments and removable tray(s)